# Using mutate and ifelse in tandem to create a new numeric variable based on a factor variable

Tags: r

Need new variable to contain a 1 if the factor variable (chargeback_date) has a record and a 0 if it is missing a record. The factor variable is `chargeback_date` and the new variable I am trying to create is `chargeback`. `chargeback_rate` only has records when there is a chargeback and the rest of the records are not null, but missing and the variable is of type factor. The code I put returns a 0 for every record in my new variable `chargeback`. Here is the code:
`mutate(chargeback=as.numeric(ifelse(!is.missing(challenge$chargeback_date), 0, 1), levels = c(0,1)))`

````
69L), .Label = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", 
"2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09", 
"2020-01-10", "2020-01-11", "2020-01-12", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-14", 
"2020-01-15", "2020-01-16", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-18", "2020-01-19", 
"2020-01-20", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-22", "2020-01-23", "2020-01-24", 
"2020-01-25", "2020-01-26", "2020-01-27", "2020-01-28", "2020-01-29", 
"2020-01-30", "2020-01-31", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-03", 
"2020-02-04", "2020-02-05", "2020-02-06", "2020-02-07", "2020-02-08", 
"2020-02-09", "2020-02-10", "2020-02-11", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", 
"2020-02-14", "2020-02-15", "2020-02-16", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-18", 
"2020-02-19", "2020-02-20", "2020-02-21", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-23", 
"2020-02-24", "2020-02-25", "2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", "2020-02-28", 
"2020-02-29", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", 
"2020-03-05", "2020-03-06", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-09", 
"2020-03-10", "2020-03-11", "2020-03-12", "2020-03-13", "2020-03-14", 
"2020-03-15", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-19", 
"2020-03-20", "2020-03-21", "2020-03-22", "2020-03-23", "2020-03-24", 
"2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", "2020-03-27", "2020-03-28", "2020-03-29", 
"2020-03-30", "2020-03-31"), class = "factor"), chargeback_date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "2020-01-15", "2020-01-16", 
"2020-01-17", "2020-01-18", "2020-01-19", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-23", 
"2020-01-24", "2020-01-27", "2020-01-28", "2020-01-29", "2020-01-30", 
"2020-01-31", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-04", "2020-02-05", "2020-02-06", 
"2020-02-07", "2020-02-11", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14", 
"2020-02-15", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-19", "2020-02-20", 
"2020-02-21", "2020-02-23", "2020-02-25", "2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", 
"2020-02-28", "2020-02-29", "2020-03-02", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", 
"2020-03-05", "2020-03-06", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-10", 
"2020-03-11", "2020-03-12", "2020-03-13", "2020-03-14", "2020-03-16", 
"2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-19", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-22", 
"2020-03-23", "2020-03-24", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", "2020-03-27", 
"2020-03-29", "2020-03-30", "2020-03-31", "2020-04-01", "2020-04-02", 
"2020-04-03", "2020-04-04", "2020-04-06", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-08", 
"2020-04-09", "2020-04-10", "2020-04-11", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-13", 
"2020-04-14", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-16", "2020-04-18", "2020-04-19", 
"2020-04-20", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-22", "2020-04-23", "2020-04-24", 
"2020-04-25", "2020-04-27", "2020-04-28", "2020-04-29", "2020-04-30", 
"2020-05-01", "2020-05-04", "2020-05-06", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-08", 
"2020-05-10", "2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", "2020-05-13", "2020-05-14", 
"2020-05-15", "2020-05-16", "2020-05-18", "2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", 
"2020-05-21", "2020-05-22", "2020-05-23", "2020-05-24", "2020-05-25", 
"2020-05-26", "2020-05-27", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-29", "2020-06-01", 
"2020-06-02", "2020-06-03", "2020-06-04", "2020-06-05", "2020-06-07", 
"2020-06-08", "2020-06-09", "2020-06-10", "2020-06-11", "2020-06-13", 
"2020-06-14", "2020-06-15", "2020-06-16", "2020-06-17", "2020-06-18", 
"2020-06-19", "2020-06-22", "2020-06-23", "2020-06-24", "2020-06-25", 
"2020-06-26", "2020-06-27", "2020-06-29", "2020-06-30", "2020-07-02", 
"2020-07-06", "2020-07-07", "2020-07-09", "2020-07-11", "2020-07-13", 
"2020-07-14", "2020-07-16", "2020-07-17", "2020-07-18", "2020-07-21", 
"2020-07-22", "2020-07-23", "2020-07-24", "2020-07-27", "2020-07-28", 
"2020-07-29", "2020-07-30", "2020-07-31", "2020-08-03", "2020-08-05", 
"2020-08-06", "2020-08-11", "2020-08-14", "2020-08-17", "2020-08-18", 
"2020-08-19", "2020-08-20", "2020-08-21", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-27", 
"2020-09-04", "2020-09-07", "2020-09-08", "2020-09-09", "2020-09-17", 
"2020-09-18", "2020-09-25", "2020-10-05", "2020-10-06", "2020-10-07", 
"2020-10-12", "2020-10-18", "2020-10-27", "2020-11-03", "2020-11-06", 
"2020-11-07", "2020-11-10", "2020-11-22", "2020-11-23", "2020-12-01", 
"2020-12-04", "2020-12-07", "2020-12-14", "2020-12-18", "2020-12-23", 
"2020-12-24", "2020-12-30"), class = "factor"), authentication = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("attempted", "not attempted", 
"verified"), class = "factor"), cycle = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), order_count_attempt = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L), call_count = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), card_bin = c(2453L, 3535L, 3535L, 1882L, 1340L, 1333L), card_brand = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("", "American Express", "Discover", 
"MasterCard", "Visa"), class = "factor"), card_type = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "CREDIT", "DEBIT"), class = "factor"), 
    card_is_prepaid = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "false", "true"), class = "factor"), card_bank_id = c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), card_level = structure(c(7L, 17L, 17L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("", "AADVANTAGE", "BUSINESS", "CCSG LENDING", 
    "CCSG US CONSUMER REVOLVE", "CENTURION", "CLASSIC", "COMPANY", 
    "COMPANY REVOLVE", "CONSUMER CHARGE", "CONSUMER LENDING", 
    "CONSUMER LIMITS EXPANSION", "CONSUMER REVOLVE", "CORPORATE", 
    "CORPORATE T&E", "DELTA REWARDS", "ENHANCED", "EXECUTIVE BUSINESS", 
    "FLEET", "GIFT", "GOLD", "INFINITE", "MIXED PRODUCT", "OPEN CHARGE", 
    "OPEN GREEN REVOLVE", "OPEN LENDING", "OPTIMA", "OTHER", 
    "PERSONAL", "PERSONAL GOLD REVOLVE", "PERSONAL GREEN CHARGE", 
    "PERSONAL GREEN PREPAID", "PERSONAL GREEN REVOLVE", "PERSONAL REVOLVE", 
    "PLATINUM", "PREPAID", "PREPAID BUSINESS", "PREPAID CORPORATE T&E", 
    "PREPAID EMPLOYEE INCENTIVE", "PREPAID GOVERNMENT", "PREPAID HEALTHCARE", 
    "PREPAID HEALTHCARE NON-TAX", "PREPAID HSA NON-SUBSTANTIATED", 
    "PREPAID PAYROLL", "PREPAID PLATINUM TRAVEL", "PREPAID PURCHASING", 
    "PREPAID RELOADABLE", "PREPAID WORKPLACE B2B", "PROFESSIONAL", 
    "PURCHASING", "PURCHASING WITH FLEET", "REVOLVE", "SIGNATURE", 
    "STANDARD", "TRIUMPH - SBS LIMITS", "WORLD", "WORLD ELITE", 
    "WORLD ELITE FOR BUSINESS", "WORLD FOR BUSINESS"), class = "factor"), 
    gateway_id = c(108L, 87L, 106L, 106L, 86L, 106L), state_id = structure(c(13L, 
    51L, 51L, 19L, 29L, 19L), .Label = c("", "AE", "AK", "AL", 
    "AP", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", 
    "GU", "HI", "IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", 
    "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", 
    "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "PR", 
    "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", "VT", "WA", "WI", 
    "WV", "WY"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame") ```
````

Comment: Hello. First, `mutate` takes a dataframe as the first argument and the definition of new columns as the subsequent arguments, and returns a data frame that contains new columns instead of a new variable. If you want to create a new variable, you don't need to use `mutate` but just `chargeback = as.numeric(...)`. If you want to add columns to the data frame, `mutate(challenge, chargeback=...`.

Comment: I think it will be much easier for folks to help if you could post a small example of your data using dput() and the expected output. of your code.

Comment: So prior to the code I have above, I have ```challenge <- read.csv("challenge_dataset.csv")#%>%```

Comment: The dataset is 40056 observations of 14 variables, so the dput is a little hard to read. The chargeback_date column is of type factor and it doesn't contain any data or N/A values for records where there was no chargeback. For records where there is a chargeback, there is a date formatted 'DD-MM-YYYY'

Comment: You could use dput(head()) to share a smaller fraction of the dataset so people can verify their answers have the expected result. Help the helpers to help you.

Comment: Sweet thanks. I just added the dput(head(challenge)) to the original question

Comment: It seems that the beginning of `dput` output is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
df$chargeback <- as.integer(df$chargeback_date != '')
```

Comment: This just returned 1 for the entire variable

Comment: @BryceWilkings Can you try the updated answer.

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Comment: any idea how I can use the new variable to try and predict the number of chargebacks using regression?

Comment: You can ask that as a new question. Also check `?lm`